# bash prompt: highlight command being entered

Tags: bash, prompt

Entering a command on bash goes like this:

```
<Prompt $>  <The Command I Entered>
<Output Of The Command>
```

I'm looking a way to make `The Command I Entered` bold.
It's easy to start bold from prompt with putting `tput bold` in PS1.

However the questions is, how to  `tput sgr0` it when `Enter` is pressed.
Can i use readline / bash magic to achieve this?

Comment: You can set the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to `tput sgr0` which will execute after the command and prior to each prompt being displayed.

Comment: It's not executed before the output of the command is displayed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pre Bash 4.4:**

In bash 4.3.x (and maybe earlier), the "debug trap" is executed before a command from the command line is executed.

```
trap 'tput sgr0' DEBUG
```

But this has one disadvantage: It is executed before every simple command that is executed. So if you run:

```
$ echo Hello && echo World
```

The debug trap is called two times.

Then the following command will **not** work as expected:

```
tput setaf 1 ; echo "This is red"
```

The printed "This is red" will not be red.

See [DEBUG trap and PROMPT_COMMAND in Bash](https://jichu4n.com/posts/debug-trap-and-prompt_command-in-bash/) and also the accepted answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412900/reset-the-color-of-the-output-after-my-command-in-bash-shell).

**Bash 4.4**

In Bash 4.4 the variable `$PS0` was introduced. Here is a quote from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING  below)
>   and  displayed  by  interactive shells after reading a command
>   and before the command is executed.

So with bash 4.4 you could do the following:

```
PS0="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

The `\[\]` are used to enclose unprintable characters (here the terminal control sequence to reset text attributes). I'm not sure if this is really needed for `PS0`, but it can't hurt. There is no visual difference in the shell output either way.

Comment: `\[\]` are needed to ensure the shell computes the proper length from the actual sequence of characters produced between them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I know that, updated the last sentence to make it (hopefully) clearer.

Answer (score 1):

To extend [Ralf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54733024/2002471) to make the command **bold** in bash **4.4+** requires setting `PS1` and `PS0` like so:

```
PS1="\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \t \W \\$\[\e[0;30;1m\] "
PS0="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Obviously you might not like my boring prompt, but it gives you a starting place with the command in bold.  The `\[\e[0;30;1m\]` is setting the command to be displayed in black text and bold.  Other [color choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) may suit you better.

I found this handy when using [asciinema](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema) to capture examples for documentation.  It reminds me of the [O'Reilly style](http://oreillymedia.github.io/production-resources/styleguide/#typography_and_font_conventions) of including UNIX console examples with the command in bold.